# responsive horizontal to off canvas accordian menu slideToggle issue

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Need help!!!

For a responsive dropdown menu wherein the horizontal dropdown turns to off canvas three level accordian menu from 900px downwards, having problem in slideToggling the children levels nor is the sliding effect happening...though the horizontal to off canvas works fine. Somewhere there is something wrong with the css and definitely the Jquery....very raw in jquery...please help!

the jquery used is following...but guess it is to do with css also...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = "open";
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        if (menu == "close") {
            $('.menu-toggle').css('content', '\f00d');
            $('.mainnav').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0,0)');
            $('#menu').addClass('mobile');
            $('.sub, .has-sub li').click(function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(this).children('.has-sub, .sub-item').slideToggle();
            });
            menu = "open";
        } else {
            $('.menu-toggle').css('content', '\f0c9');
            $('.mainnav').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(100%,0)');
            $('#menu').removeClass('mobile');
            menu = "close";
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see from the below link, not using any framework.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arindamsg23/a24xvjd1/

Thanks a million in advance for support!